# Why could flask fail at serving one file from a static directory but succeeds at serving another one from the same directory

Tags: python, apache, flask

In my flask-based web-app I am serving the front-end that was built in React as static files.

I am getting very odd behavior: when I host the app using Apache2 on Linux, I see that app successfully (200) serves the file `.../static/js/2.38fbad81.chunk.js`, but it fails (404) on `.../static/js/main.a8634485.chunk.js` .

These files are in the same directory and the api requests are processed by the exact same code. What could possibly be causing the one to fail where the other one succeeds?

The flask code involved seems to be the line

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='web-app-build/build/')
```

which automatically goes to look for calls starting with `static` in that location. At least, this seems to be the case when I run it through Aapache on Linux. When I run the code from python on my development machine (Windows, serving to localhost:9000), I seem to need the code

```
static_dir = os.path.abspath("./web-app-build/build/static/")

@app.route('/static/<path:filename>')
def serve_asset1(filename):
    parts = filename.split("/")
    real_dir = os.path.join(static_dir, *parts[:-1])
    return send_from_directory(real_dir, parts[-1])
```

And in this case everything works.

I did double check that both the files exist in the said directory. This one really has me stuck any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file that isn't being served?

Comment: @JohnGordon: it is `-rw-r--r--` on all the files in that directory.

Comment: Hmm.  Is the successful filename in your question correct?  i.e. it ends in `.chunk`?

Comment: #JohnGordon: ah no, looks like i accidentally omitted the `.js` at then end. I'll correct that in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there was nothing mysterious about this in the end.

At some point I had copied a folder into `/static/` (as opposed to `/web-app-build/build/static/` and then I forgot about it. This forgotten folder contained the one file and not the other and somehow, when the stuff is run by Apache in Linux, it seems to draw from the forgotten folder instead of the remembered one.

On to figuring out why that is and how to fix it.